# Debugging non-browser HTTP requests in PHP

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I'm building a PHP server that responds to http GET/POST requests from mobile applications.

I'm fairly ok with using xdebug to debug http requests that are initiated via my browser etc.  Using xdebug if I enter a url in my browser and set an appropriate breakpoint in PHPStorm - there's no problem.

How do you do it for a non-browser request ? In my case I'm writing an iPhone / Android app that collects GPS location data and then POSTs the data via HTTP after JSON and urlencoding to my server for storage/analysis.

Running my app in the XCode simulator or Eclipse for example I can get an idea of what the server thinks it received from my app by echoing back what it received with an HTTPResponse.

What are the alternatives? Do I just have to log the incoming content data to file on my server, or is it possible to set breakpoints using an alternative to xdebug ?

Would appreciate any tips or pointers! Thanks!

Comment: Keep using xdebug -- it's a debugger and the end of the day, not some "http debug helper". Just **1)** configure your xdebug to debug **every** request (`xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` -- http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_autostart ) and **2)** use "zero-config" approach: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: **Alternatively:** PhpStorm has "PHP HTTP Request" type of Run/Debug Configuration -- use it for debug specific GET/POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

By using a debugging proxy such as Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/), you can set your mobile device to route requests through the proxy application.

You can then view the request and response headers and body.

Charles also provides various helpful features such as allowing you to edit and repeat requests.

Comment: Most mobile devices (android and iOS definitely) can be set to use a proxy